# Sum of adjacency matrices in connected graph G

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

If G is connected graph, then show that there is no $0$ element in matrix $A+A^2+A^3+\cdots+A^{n-1}$ where A is adjacency matrix of G, and n number of vertices. If we are looking at element on position $ij$ where $i\ne j$ then it is clear(because G is connected) that there must exist path with length of at least one of the numbers $1,2,\cdots,n-1$. But how can we know that elements on position where $i=j$ will be non zero, because this graph does not need to have a cycle right, so maybe there is not closed path in it? Or I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are forgetting that the walks counted by the powers of the adjacency matrix can come and go through the same edge (because it is a walk, not a path).

Simple example:

\begin{align*}
A &=\left[\begin{array}[cc]
00 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
A^2&=\left[\begin{array}[cc]
01 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

PS: Walks are "paths" where you are allowed to repeat edges and vertices.

Comment: But in path vertices cant be repeated right? So if we come back with same edges some of vertices can be repeated?

Comment: Yeah sorry. I didn't mean path. The things that the powers adjacency matrix count aren't paths, it counts walks in the graph.

Comment: Oh right, totally forgot that in adjaceny matrix we have walks and not necessarily
path. Thanks!